# Raft project setup for web automation testing

Tags: selenium, testing, automation, automated-tests, raft

Where can I learn and build a raft project? Can't find anything on Google and YouTube. Can I use a selenium code to run in raft?

I googled a lot but there is no documentation regarding raft where I can learn how to setup a project and start working on test automation.

Comment: > Can I use a selenium code to run in raft

Please elaborate what you are trying to achieve with this?

Answer (score 1):

It depends what are your goals. For example:

- if you want to build raft itself, then the best approach is to use the original paper: https://raft.github.io/raft.pdf
- if you want to build a product based on raft, then I highly recommend to pick a library from https://raft.github.io/#implementations Many of those libraries have good documentation, including testing related procedures